# Statement to delete old versions of an entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have several versions assigned to a DocumentID.

```
DocID  Version
ABC    1
ABC    2
ABC    3
DEF    1
DEF    2
```

How can I delete the older versions and only keep the most recent? After the delete, this should remain in the table:

```
DocID  Version
ABC    3
DEF    2
```

Comment: If it's SQL Server, why is it also tagged `mysql`? And can you specify the version of SQL Server?

Comment: typo on mysql - SQL Server version is 2012

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT DocID, Version, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY DocID ORDER BY Version DESC)
  FROM dbo.tablename
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;
```

For SQL Server 2000 it's a little more complex. (It's always useful to include version information.)

```
DELETE t
FROM dbo.tablename AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT DocID, Version = MAX(Version)
  FROM dbo.tablename
  GROUP BY DocID
) AS t2
ON t.DocID = t2.DocID
AND t.Version = t2.Version
WHERE t2.DocID IS NULL;
```

Apparently this latter query [will work in MySQL as well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4055c/1) (thanks @bluefeet).

<strike>For MySQL you're on your own, you may be better off posting a completely different question.</strike>

Comment: I believe your second query will work in MySql [see sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4055c/1), so you can edit your answer. :)

Comment: @TonyC on SQL Server 2012, the first version should be much better. Did you try it?